WhatsApp - merge messages from old phone when new phone has been active for some time
My wife broke her android phone a little while back. She got a new phone, used her original phone number and installed WhatsApp on it. She hadn't backed up her WhatsApp messages on her old phone and started afresh with her new phone and so has a chat history there.
I have since managed to fix her old phone sufficiently that I can access her old WhatsApp but of course it no longer "runs" as her new phone is the connected device. Is it possible to access the old messages and merge them into a complete overall chat history?

Possible dupe: Merging WhatsApp chat histories from different devices but same account

Looking at that question it seems it's no longer appropriate unfortunately.
